# Limiting result in country with Google Place autocomplete?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I just tried [this demo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete), but I can't find how to limit result in country.
I also checked getAutocompletePredictions in com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi, but I can't found any document to implement limiting country.

I also searched some questions in SO; apparently it's JavaScript and needs to add some "optional param". So how to add optional param in this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search

1. you can add the country name in the query , such as "in australia" to limit search in australia

or

2 . add a radius parameter to limit the search

Comment: Can you tell me about add radius parameter ?
(Notes: I working on Android place api).
THanks

Comment: i believe there is no sdk for google map place search for neither ios nor android.

if you are working on some framework , i can't help

but if you try to work on the api by yourself 

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&types=museum&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

Comment: Do you check: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete

Current I use your suggest: add "in + country" -> it working :)
But I want to know how to implement "param" in method: com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi#getAutocompletePredictions

Answer (score 0):

should be this way, but it doesn't work, due to a bug in google play service library v7?

```
List<Integer> autocompleteFilter = new ArrayList<Integer>();
autocompleteFilter.add(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY);

// Set up the adapter that will retrieve suggestions from the Places Geo Data API that cover
// the entire world.
mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
BOUNDS_JAKARTA, AutocompleteFilter.create(autocompleteFilter));
```

Comment: Thanks. But what do you think about "bounds" :|, I think bound can't correct because have nothing country have sqr is Rectangle. :|